# How to use a string as an instruction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert a string into an instruction that I can use in my Python-3 code.
For example, if I have multiple strings in a list, I want to convert each string into a "code" that I can use like this `self.ids.'converted_string'.do_something`.

I saw other posts using `exec()` or `setattr()`, but in the first case I don't want to convert my string into a variable with a value, and in the other case I don't have an object to modify.

I might be misunderstanding how those function work (maybe they can work for me?), but then I don't know how to use them.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?  This can be done but is generally considered (very?) bad practice.  That is to say: there is probably a better way to do what you need to.

Comment: Dynamically executing strings as code is *almost always* not the right way to do things. What is it that you are actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: "in the other case I don't have an object to modify." Then what exactly do you expect your string to do?!

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about an *attribute*. Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) like this:

```
getattr(self.ids, 'converted_string').do_something
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> getattr(object, name[, default])
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x, 'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

So you can do:

```
getattr(self.ids, 'converted_string').do_something
```